Chainlink function is executed but NFT is not minted
I am using Remix IDE with compiler version pragma solidity 0.8.20. Basically the contract calls an external API using Chainlink functions to get a character name that will be used when minting the NFT. I am deploying the contract and adding it to the Chainlink function subscriber. Then when calling mintSendRequest the transaction goes through but the NFT is not minted. The subscriber UI says the calculation was done but the callback failed. What can be the error? Here de contract code:
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity 0.8.20;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/access/Ownable.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Base64.sol";
import {FunctionsClient} from "@chainlink/contracts@1.1.0/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/FunctionsClient.sol";
import {ConfirmedOwner} from "@chainlink/contracts@1.1.0/src/v0.8/shared/access/ConfirmedOwner.sol";
import {FunctionsRequest} from "@chainlink/contracts@1.1.0/src/v0.8/functions/v1_0_0/libraries/FunctionsRequest.sol";

contract MintWithAPI is ERC721URIStorage, ConfirmedOwner, FunctionsClient {
    using FunctionsRequest for FunctionsRequest.Request;

    address router = 0xA9d587a00A31A52Ed70D6026794a8FC5E2F5dCb0;
    bytes32 donID = 0x66756e2d6176616c616e6368652d66756a692d31000000000000000000000000;
    bytes public s_lastResponse;
    bytes public s_lastError;
    bytes32 public s_lastRequestId;
    address public addressTo;
    string public character;
    event Response(bytes32 indexed requestId, string character, bytes response, bytes err);

    string source = "const characterId = args[0];"
        "const apiResponse = await Functions.makeHttpRequest({"
        "url: `https://swapi.dev/api/people/${characterId}/`"
        "});"
        "if (apiResponse.error) {"
        "throw Error('Request failed');"
        "}"
        "const { data } = apiResponse;"
        "return Functions.encodeString(data.name);";

    uint256 private _nextTokenId;
    uint32 gasLimit = 300000;

    // Custom error type
    error UnexpectedRequestID(bytes32 requestId);

    constructor() FunctionsClient(router) ConfirmedOwner(msg.sender) ERC721("MintWithAPI", "MWA") {
    }

    function mintSendRequest(address to, string[] calldata args, uint64 subscriptionId) external onlyOwner returns (bytes32 requestId) {
        addressTo = to;
        FunctionsRequest.Request memory req;
        req.initializeRequestForInlineJavaScript(source);
        if (args.length > 0) req.setArgs(args);
        s_lastRequestId = _sendRequest(req.encodeCBOR(), subscriptionId, gasLimit, donID);
    
        require(s_lastRequestId != bytes32(0), "Request failed");
        return s_lastRequestId;
    }

    function getTokenURI(uint256 tokenId) public view returns (string memory) { 
        bytes memory dataURI = abi.encodePacked(
            '{',
            '"name": "', character, '",',
            '"tokenId": "', Strings.toString(tokenId), '",',
            '"description": "This is a proof of concept NFT",',
            '"image": "https://bafybeiawfshhlcmng5vjkphw7dwbdcpzwf374itf2dsc5shpyz6vejrctm.ipfs.dweb.link/"',
            '}'
        );
        return string(
            abi.encodePacked(
            "data:application/json;base64,",
            Base64.encode(dataURI)
            )
        );
    }

    function mintFulfillRequest() internal {
        uint256 tokenId = _nextTokenId++;
        _safeMint(addressTo, tokenId);
        _setTokenURI(tokenId, getTokenURI(tokenId));
    }

    function fulfillRequest(
        bytes32 requestId,
        bytes memory response,
        bytes memory err
    ) internal override {
        if (s_lastRequestId != requestId) {
            revert UnexpectedRequestID(requestId); // Check if request IDs match
        }
        // Update the contract's state variables with the response and any errors
        s_lastResponse = response;
        character = string(response);
        s_lastError = err;

        // Emit an event to log the response
        emit Response(requestId, character, s_lastResponse, s_lastError);
        mintFulfillRequest();
    }
}

Here an example of a transaction: https://testnet.snowtrace.io/tx/0xd97dbd49b1b930f932b95dd860d19371498905758a4aedfbd53e7f08b228e3f2?chainId=43113
Here the Chainlink subscriber feedback for that transacion:


Hey @jose so fulfillRequest() is where the callback from Functions happens.  What is the value of s_lastError?
It may be - 0x.  The other alternative is to click on the red callback failed button and see what the reason is. It could be too much gas because your callback is also calling the mint function.  maybe remove mintFulfillRequest() from the callback and run that manually at first. If that DOES work then use chainlink Automation to call that function separately.  The callback gas limit of 300K may be being exceeded.

Hey @ZeusLawyer, I ran both the chainlink function and the minting logic in separated contracts and both work. When running everything together and  clicking the red callback button in the Chainlink Function UI it says: "One frequent reason for failure is too much gas being used." A recent txn I tried says that the used gas for the txn was 98%, here the link: https://testnet.snowtrace.io/tx/0xd97dbd49b1b930f932b95dd860d19371498905758a4aedfbd53e7f08b228e3f2?chainId=43113

Hi Jose, when Functions says that gas is too much, it means the gas functions try to call your fulfill functions is higher than the gas limit you allow it to use in your sub balance. One solution is to increase the variable gaslimit  in your consumer contract.
